# How do I create an empty Django formset using modelformset_factory?

Tags: django-forms

I'm creating a formset, but it seems to populate it with all of the existing data in the table for that object. I can't figure out how to start with a blank formset; the only way seems to be to delete all of the data from the table, but clearly this isn't an option.

I will post code if necessary (but there's lots of it, so knowing what is relevant is tricky).

Comment: 10 years later I have your same problem. Do you find a way to solve it?

Answer (score 14):

give a parameter queryset=Model.objects.none() when making the object.

Answer (score 1):

Following Arihant's answer, I did something like this, which works:

```
class TagCreateFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None,
             queryset=None, **kwargs):
        queryset = Tag.objects.none()
        super(TagCreateFormSet, self).__init__(data, files, 
            auto_id, prefix, queryset, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it isn't possible to change the behaviour of model formset. So as a solution, I changed the data structure so that the data I want to edit is grouped by another type, and then instead I have used `inlineformset_factory`.